# Word doesn't show custom add-in icon on Windows

Tags: office-addins, office-store

I've tested my add-in on Windows, MacOS and Word Online and it seems to exhibit this behavior only on Windows.

I've added a new button for my add-in in the manifest. When I sideload the add-in, it doesn't show the customized icon on Home Tab, it displays default add-in icon.

- All icon urls are https.
- I've defined all icon sizes (16,20,24,32,40,48,64,80) as icon resources.

Any ideas?

Comment: Seeing the part of the manifest which is not being picked up would help. Also - sounds like you're side-loading the manifest - how did you side-load it on Windows?

Comment: Any luck? Did you figure out why it wasn't being picked up?

Comment: Yeah, I solved it